# Ubuntu 18.04 editing netplan in nano "etc/netplan /01-netcfg.yaml line 1 column 9: mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Tags: wireless, network-manager, devices

So, quite simply, I'm beyond frustrated right now. I bought this PC two days ago from a guy who has XFCE downloaded on it and had Wicd as the network utility, NOT NetworkManager. I've had issues joining wifi and it usually happens after I restart my computer or close/reopen the lid. Network manager displays the following and it is grayed out:

```
Ethernet Network
device not managed
Wi-Fi Networks
device not ready
```

Wicd would say "no wireless networks found" no matter how many times I refreshed the networks list. I tried restarting network manager through command line and no luck. Sometimes I got lucky whenever I booted my computer and it would be fine. I have no means of internet connection even via ethernet so I cant update files or download anything via apt-get.

After researching the forums, I've read it could be a power management issue and/or a netplan issue. As such, I've delved into the netplan directory in an attempt to reset the netplan configuration file to be blank or "stock" if you will. After editing the file via nano, I get:

```
Invalid YAML at /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 1 column 9: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

I dont know how to enter text as if it were in terminal, so i will try my best to type this out on my phone as to what the yaml file I inserted looks like.

```
network
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      dchp4: true
  wifis:
    wlp12s0:
      dchp4: true
      accespoints:
```

Each successive indentation represents 2 spaces with the spacebar.

Comment: Ok I did that. Now it says that there are no defined accesspoints. How can I enter that? I know the network name and password

Comment: Status please...

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @steeldriver correctly noticed, you were missing the : on the network line.

I've added the accesspoints wireless name and password. Edit that as required.

Make sure to retain the indentation, spacing, and no tabs. Copy/paste the entire text.

```
network: 
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets: 
    enp9s0: 
      dchp4: true
  wifis:
    wlp12s0: 
      dchp4: true
      accespoints: 
        "network_ssid_name": 
          password: "**********"
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply config

`reboot` # assure proper operation

---

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` file should only contain this...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

---

If you'd rather stick with NetworkManager (which would make connecting to various wireless networks easier), then your .yaml file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # make config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply config

`reboot` # assure proper operation

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `:` at the end of the first line:

```
network:
  version: 2
```